# Setting JDK for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

It's been a while since I have been using eclipse.

I am working with a MacBook Pro on a project which need to be compiled with JDK 1.5.

Current installed JDK is 1.6. After having checked, the User Default Compliance settings is set to 1.5.

However on the build path it is set 1.6 as a jre system library, and there's no way of adding the 1.5 along with the official JDK, because 1.6 is the only option.

I am tempted to install jdk 1.5, but I am not sure I am able to install one for Mac without messing up the system.

**EDIT**

I have already searched trough SO, even the answer mentioned. The point is that with a Mac OSX, there's no easy way to have a JDK 1.5, even changing build path settings doesn't help.

One of the class that throws error is an implementation of javax.sql.DataSource, which change significantly from 1.5 to 1.6 by the addition of an wrapper interface.

Comment: Which compilation errors do you get? Setting compiler compliance for your project is actually enough. What you see in the Buildpath is the installed JRE on which your application will run when launched from eclipse. 1.6 JRE should run 1.5 classes just fine.

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by clicking link "Configure Workspace Setting.." as shown in image.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is still rising the same compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna to use another jre system library you need to go to your  projecte configure buid path, and remove the old library and add the library that you wanna use it.

So if you can't do it you need to go to windows/preferences/installed jre,  and install another.

I hope it helps.

Comment: On build path, there's no option of adding other jdk than 1.6, and installing another JDK system wide is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: if ypou need jdk1.5 you need to install...windows/preferences/installed jre, and install another. and then add first part.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose the compile version of JDK.